# Not including data type in variable name

Tags: kotlin, naming-conventions

In a PR I got some suggestions to rename my variables. Suggestions were made to fi. concat `*MutableLiveData`.

```
private val _state = MutableLiveData<AppointmentsUiState>()
val state: LiveData<AppointmentsUiState>
    get() = _state
```

My two variables. It's an Android ViewModel. After the suggestions I agree that perhaps `uiState` would be beter. However, 2 suggestions were `stateMutableLiveData` and `stateObservable`. I don't like those names, but my problem is that I can't think of a *valid* reason to not use their suggestions, other than:

- Uncle Bob says not to put data types into names
- Observable can be a type, it's not an Observable; it's LiveData which happens to be observable.
- It feels yucky

Why wouldn't one put data types in variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Redundancy

You can see the type of your variables so if you write their type in their name, you just duplicate the information.

- Maintanability

You couple the variable to its type, so if you change the type, you have to change the name.

- Ambiguity

If your variable has multiple interfaces, you would have to chose one of them.

Comment: Unless the language requires an explicit type in a variable declaration it is not always so easy to find the type of a variable. This is the main advantage of enforced explicit static typing which is not the case with Kotlin.

Comment: if you use a modern IDE, you will see the inferred type, which is almost always sufficient.

Comment: Any programming language which requires an advanced IDE to be used effectively is a failure in my book.